# How can I add a url path prefix to my product and category URLs in Magento?

Tags: magento

I would like my magento category and product URLs to be something like the following:

```
www.example.com/products/category-slug/
www.example.com/products/category-slug/product-slug/
```

By default, with Catalog URL rewrites enabled, I get urls like:

```
www.example.com/category-slug/
www.example.com/category-slug/product-slug/
```

I want to keep category url rewrites enabled, for the SEO benefits.

### Context:

I am building a site where I need to integrate Magento and a 3rd party content management system. I am doing this by defining a new default root block for the `cms_index_defaultnoroute` layout handle that handles non-magento pages by fetching content from the CMS (as described on [this magento wiki page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/tutorial-integrating-3rd-party-cms-content-within-magento/)). By putting the catalog urls at a different url path, I avoid possible url path collisions with pages managed by the CMS.

Comment: Be careful, the noroute page may always give a HTTP response of 404, which is bad for SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to put the store code in the URLs - an admin setting that you can just turn on. In your htaccess you can decide how you want to play it - the 404 pages handled by Magento or the CMS.

If you want everything not handled by the CMS to be handled by Magento (which leaves you options to do things with noroute controller):

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(page-not-found|terms-and-conditions|projects|privacy-policy|contact|P[0-9]{2,8}) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /othercms.php/$1 [L]
```

Put your CMS 'root pages' in the ReWriteCond or do it the other way round, depending on what you have where.
Then, for your other CMS, rename `index.php` to `othercms.php` and you should be set.

Comment: Thanks Mathew. I think that will work - to change the store base URL via the admin, and then use htaccess to rewrite those store URLs to my <web_root>/index.php (the Magento index.php file). That will  result in all my store URL paths starting with the same path component (e.g. store/) but that is fine by me.

Comment: I did it without using the store code but it was a big ugly mess as I hated the CMS that was used. What CMS you got?

Comment: I'm integrating Magento as the store portion of an existing Django powered site. It's actually gone fairly smoothly - Magento handles all requests and then fetches pages from the CMS if it cannot find them. I inject the sidebar shopping cart and catalog navigation into the CMS page with simple string replaces. Maybe not the prettiest approach, but it works.